# How to get the selected item from ListView?

Tags: android, listview

in my Android app I have created a ListView component called myList, and filled it with  objects of my own custom type:

```
class MyClass{

    private String displayName;
    private String theValue;
... //here constructor, getters, setters and toString() are implemented

}
```

I used the ArrayAdapter to bound the ArrayList theObjects with myList:

```
ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter= 
                new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this, R.layout.lay_item, theObjects);
myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works fine, the list is populated and etc., but when I'm trying to access the selected item, i receive a Null object. I've done this using

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

MyClass selItem = (MyClass) myList.getSelectedItem(); //
String value= selItem.getTheValue(); //getter method

}
```

What seems to be the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 47):

By default, when you click on a ListView item it doesn't change its state to "selected". So, when the event fires and you do:

```
myList.getSelectedItem();
```

The method doesn't have anything to return. What you have to do is to use the position and obtain the underlying object by doing:

```
myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: How does that help finding an index of a selected item? How would you get the position in the first place?

Comment: @Zelphir The position is passed into the onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) method

Comment: The behviour of this class is really confusing. After setSelection(pos), getSelectedItem() still returns null, while getSelectedItemPosition() correctly gives the right position.

Answer (score 21):

You are implementing the Click Handler rather than Select Handler. A List by default doesn't suppose to have selection.

What you should change, in your above example, is to

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    MyClass item = (MyClass) adapter.getItem(position);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the `onItemClickLitener()` will itself provide you the index of the selected item, you can simply do a `getItemAtPosition(i).toString()`. The code snippet is given below :-

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String s = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            adapter.dismiss(); // If you want to close the adapter
        }
    });
```

On the method above, the `i` parameter actually gives you the position of the selected item.

Answer (score 6):

On **onItemClick** :

```
String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: Works for xamarin :)

Answer (score 3):

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
      MyClass selItem = (MyClass) adapter.getItem(position);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using setOnItemClickListener is the correct answer, but if you have a keyboard you can change selection even with arrows (no click is performed), so, you need to implement also setOnItemSelectedListener :

```
myListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
     MyObject tmp=(MyObject) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
         }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // your stuff
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In [touch mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html), there is no focus and no selection. Your UI should use a different type of widget, such as radio buttons, for selection.

The documentation on ListView about this is terrible, just one obscure mention on [setSelection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Though I am using ***kotlin***, the following code answered your question. This return selected item:

```
val item = myListView.adapter.getItem(i).toString()
```

The following is the whole selecteditem Listener

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(object : OnItemClickListener {
       override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, i: Int,
                        id: Long) {
           val item = myListView.adapter.getItem(i).toString()

       }
    })
```

The code returns the item clicked by its index i as shown in the code

Answer (score -1):

> MyClass selItem = (MyClass)
>   myList.getSelectedItem(); //

You never instantiated your class.

Comment: He said he can view the stuff, so the class must have instantiated.