# Android ListView - get the selected item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have implemented a list view using a custom  array adapter. Now I want to get the selected item of the list view. I know that there are solutions using onclick listeners. However I would like to use the getSelectedItem() method of the ListView (AdapterView) class. The method always returns null. The other getSelected* methods also do not work.

```
// onCreate
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

// set in Broadcast Receiver (inner class)
    mList.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.list_view_item, R.id.textView,
                itemList));

// onButtonClick
    Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + mList.getSelectedItem());
```

OnButtonClick is a callback of a seperate button. If I click on it the selected item should be printed in logcat but it returns everytime null. Can anyone help me?

XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_blue_light" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonContinue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClickContinue"
    android:text="Continue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I select an item the color changes.

Comment: Please post your XML i think i didn't declare your items in your xml

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your application? At which situation do you want to get the selected item?

Comment: @user2572585 my bad for the misunderstanding, sorry: I removed my solution as it clearly didn't match your question.

Comment: @Rick77 No problem ;) You wanted to help. So thanks.

Comment: (*very*) dumb question: are you working in the UI thread all the time?

Comment: also, does a getItemAtPosition(0) work (trying to get my bearings)?

Comment: Yes I only use the UI thread. Could that be a problem? getItemAtPosition(0)  works fine

Comment: no, I sort of hoped you did use threads, because it could have provided a line of investigation. As for the getItemAtPosition, I have read this answer to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627960/2177061 (but I must be honest, it sound silly to me and I don't know if it's correct... Still checking, though)

Comment: also, just to be sure, could you try again after adding in the ListView's XML android:choiceMode="singleChoice" and see if something changes?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything.

Comment: last ditch effort (then, I'm completely clueless... sorry): have you tried passing the actual activity context to the Adapter instead of the one in the app? Something like new ListAdapter(MyActivityName.this, R.layout.list_view_item, R.id.textView, itemList)?

Comment: No unfortunately it didn't work. However thanks for your effort! I think I will use the solution with the listener because it looks like this is getting really time-consuming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the OnItemSelected method is never/rarely called on touch devices.
It fires up if you use the emulator cross-navigation and on special devices with hybrid or non-touch control. It is only called if you scroll through the list but not if you click on it.

Thats why you should use the OnItemClickListener on a general tablet/smartphone with touch control.

Comment: This blog post on [touch mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) has more background.

Answer (score 2):

Implement you class

```
public class xyz extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
```

then give onitemclicklistener of that activity

```
mList.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And now implement the onItemselected method

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // u will get the position and selected item here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I check the getSelectedItem source code

```
public Object getSelectedItem() {
    T adapter = getAdapter();
    int selection = getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (adapter != null && adapter.getCount() > 0 && selection >= 0) {
        return adapter.getItem(selection);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

maybe you should check your the `getItem` method in the  `ListAdapter`

Comment: chinaanihchen's answer is actuall interesting: what is the Log.d of the getAdapter, getCount, before the getSelectedItem?

Comment: Yes the answer is interesting. However the custom adapter is not the problem. It seems everything OK. I also tried it with an ArrayAdapter and I get the same problem.