# getSelectedItem() from ListView on button click

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to retrieve the selected item of a `ListView` when user clicks a button. I am using the below code in `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
lvequipments.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Object o = lvequipments.getItemAtPosition(i);
            CustomerEquipmentView customerEquipmentView = (CustomerEquipmentView)o;
            Product product = workOrderPresenter.getCustomerModel().getProduct(customerEquipmentView);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), customerEquipmentView.getModelName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

And the toast is successfully getting the model name from the object when I select different items in the `ListView`. Outside the `ListView` I have a button that saves some data from a different panel. I am attempting to retrieve the `ListView` item again here like so

```
public void saveToDatabase() {
        Object o = lvequipments.getSelectedItem();
        CustomerEquipmentView customerEquipmentView = (CustomerEquipmentView)o;
        ...
}
```

But `o` is null. Evaluating `lvequipments.getSelectedItem()` at a breakpoint during run also gives null. How do I successfully retrieve the selected item from the `ListView` from outside the `onItemClick()` method?

Comment: why do you expect `getSelectedItem` to return anything? Is something selected in your listview?

Comment: When you click on item in listview doesn't that become the selected?

Comment: no. it the listview is in a CHOICE_MODE that is not NONE, it can become checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. define an int field in class, like int SelectedItemIndex
2. in onItemSelected(...) method write SelectedItemIndex = i
3. in savetodatabase method get the selected element by lvequipments.getItemAtPosition(SelectedItemIndex);
   that what you want i think

Comment: Is this the only way? Why doesn't getSelectedItem() work, it seems like that should be a painless way to retrieve selected item

Comment: I am still new to android so I am not sure exact differences between two handlers, but referring to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399757/android-listview-get-the-selected-item he says onItemClick is better for tablet. At any rate your answer is working for me