# How to get the position of a selected item in ListView, onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get the position of a **selected item** like this:

```
//more code (adapter settings etc)
List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String selected_item= String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                    position=(Integer)List.getTag(); //without this line it doesn't crash
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Please Log-In"+selected_item+"Thesi :"+String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent toy = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(toy);
                }
            });
```

It results on *crashing* my app.

> Goal: i would like to have in a public variable (***position***) the
>   position of a selected item

Logcat:

```
12-03 18:16:31.858 4421-4421/gr.aegean.icsd.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Let me mention that i'm new with android studio.

Comment: please show us your logcat

Comment: You should see the below link I think this may help you. [See the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834750/how-to-get-the-selected-item-from-listview)

Comment: i added the logcat

Comment: change to this `position=(Integer)view.getTag();`

Comment: still crashes the app

Comment: put the code when you declare the adapter and set the adapter to the listview, also put your custom adapter class.

Comment: i already have done that before declaring this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a ListView which you want to add listener to. In that case, in onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l)  method, third parameter **int i** holds the position.

**Edit:**
If you want to use int i in another activity, the easiest way is to declare a static class variable in the same activity where the **setOnItemclick** is. For example:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    // variable accessible from anywhere in your package
    static int global_int;

    // other usual code...

    // your existing code
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String selected_item= String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                position=(Integer)List.getTag(); //without this line it doesn't crash
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Please Log-In"+selected_item+"Thesi :"+String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent toy = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(toy);

                // saving "i"
                global_int=i;
            }
        });

}
```

Then from any other place in your code, other activity, etc. you access it like this:

```
int get_global_int=MainActivity.global_int;
```

There are other ways like saving it in SharedPreferences, but this is the easiest one.

Comment: Indeed, it was really simple, all i have to do now is  to store it into a different variable. Thank you for your reply

Comment: how can i use the 'i' in a different activity?

Answer (score 1):

try this it will give you the selected item value and its position.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3)
    {
        String selectedFromList =(String) (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        Log.d("Selected: ",  selectedFromList );


       int selectedItemPosition = listview.getItemAtPosition(position));

        Log.d("Selected item position :- ", selectedItemPosition);

    }
});
```

and **YOU CAN STORE THIS ITEM POSITION** in an int variable , see above modified code , i stored the selected item position in an int variable selectedItemPosition. you can use this `selectedItemPosition` wherever you want.

Comment: i get the item when i click on it on the log cat, i want to store the viriable position and try to use it in a different activity

Comment: check the modified code , it works , hope it solve your problem and get your upvote.

Comment: glad it works for you Phill,  yes you need to declare your item global if you want to use that outside the scope of this function